# How to compare style properties with the default style?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm trying to create a 'Dark Mode' for my Windows application, but I want to keep the basic default style of the controls and just change the colours. I have downloaded a VCL style (Windows 10 Charcoal) and converted it to an FMX style using the Bitmap Style Designer. It looks mostly ok. However, there are some annoying differences.

I can open the Style Designer to edit the parameters, but it's difficult to know what to change. I'd like to compare the parameters with the default style to see what's different, but how do I do that? The default style seems to be hardcoded and not visible in the Style Designer.

[Here is a demo application of the issues I'm having](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1adfM0ZtX22kzyfb5AMiIoX_bboeAO6Dj/view?usp=sharing). Build it in Delphi 11.2 for Windows 32-bit. After running you can click the checkbox to switch between styles. I have 2 issues when in Dark Mode.

1. The borders of the form change. All the components on the form shift because of this. I'd like only the colours to change. I assume that I need to change some parameters in windowborderstyle in the Style Designer, but playing around with those parameters hasn't helped much.
2. The main menu behaves differently. In normal light mode I can click File for example and then move the cursor over Edit and Edit will automatically open and File will close. However, that doesn't happen in Dark Mode. File just stays open. I don't know what to change in the style to fix it. Interestingly, a TMenuBar object is the opposite. Normally the menu doesn't work as it should and with the dark style it does!

If I had all the parameters of the default style (light) then I could compare with the parameters of the dark style to try to work out what the differences are and maybe fix these issues. But I don't know how to do that?

Comment: check this project it might help   https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-utils

Comment: Look at Vcl Styles Utils NC (Demo App) under DEMO

Comment: @ShlomoAbuisak Thanks, but can you be more specific about how it might help with my issues? There's not much documentation there.

Comment: @XylemFlow see the menu in the demo that works ok
why invent the weel?

Comment: I was about to check out your problem, but I cannot download the demo from the site where you posted it. Please never post sample code anywhere else than in your question! The question including sample code MUST be complete within the question post according to rules of Stack Overflow!

Comment: @Tom Brunberg I did not have a problem downloading even now

Comment: @TomBrunberg, the problem is that the sample code contains a style, which includes image data. It's not really feasible to post that as text. How would you recommend I do it? You can't attach files here as far as I can see.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, I've changed the link. You should be able to access it now. I tried putting the code as text but it exceeded the character limit.